# why my prompt saying the invalid syntex for @class in scrapy?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
country = response.xpath("//span[@class = "t20-country"]/a/@href")
  File "<ipython-input-11-c41a32446215>", line 1
    country = response.xpath("//span[@class = "t20-country"]/a/@href")
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i tried in all IDLE but the result is same please help me out...!

Comment: is `t20-country` a variable? If so you aren't concatenating properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are invalid (`"` inside `""`).

Change this:

```py
country = response.xpath("//span[@class = "t20-country"]/a/@href")
```

To this:

```py
country = response.xpath('//span[@class = "t20-country"]/a/@href')
```